# How to specify input dimensions in deploy.prototxt for forward propagation when using OpenCV 3.3 to load Caffe models

Tags: c++, opencv, conv-neural-network, caffe

On specifying the input layer in deploy.prototxt as

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 200 dim: 400 } }
}
```

I get the error:  "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "input_param".

On specifying the input layer as

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_shape: { dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 200 dim: 400 }
}
```

I get the error:  "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "input_shape".

On specifying the input as

```
input:"data"
input_dim:1
input_dim:1
input_dim:200
input_dim:400
```

I am able to proceed with forward propagation. The problem with this approach is that no matter what I specify as input_dim I get the same output.

for example these 3 variations of input dims give the same output values:

```
input:"data"
input_dim:1
input_dim:1
input_dim:200
input_dim:400

input:"data"
input_dim:1
input_dim:1
input_dim:400
input_dim:200

input:"data"
input_dim:1
input_dim:1
input_dim:1
input_dim:1
```

So my question is how should the input layer be specified for deploy.prototxt

Comment: what version of caffe are you using? `input_param` was introduced later than other parameters...

Comment: what architecture are you using? is it possible one of your earlier layers `reshape`s the net?

Comment: Hi, @Shai, I am currently using the caffe model integrated in OpenCV 3.3 i.e cv::dnn for forward propagation. The input layer is the first layer there is nothing before the Input layer. I have already trained the  model but facing an issue while using it for testing. This is how I proceed: I take an input image resize it to height = 200, width =  400 ( This is the size of image used for training ) and feed it to the trained cnn, using cv::dnn.

Comment: @Shai ... do you want me to post the entire deploy.prototxt and the c++ opencv code that i am using??